# SSRS to get full URL for a parameter given directly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report having the following URL where ProjectsByCounty is the name of the report.

http://server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/ReportFolder/ReportName

I have a parameter named countyname where I can select from a dropdown like Polk or collier or Desoto and click on view report button

I need to get the URLs directly for the following and then generate a PDF.I am trying to use the following URL

http://Server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/ReportFolder/ReportName&ParmaterName=polk&rs:Format=PDF\

But it is leading to the enter Parameter step

Can someone help what the URL should be to directly generate a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:                          http://Server/ReportsServerName/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?
/ReportFolder/ReportName&ParmaterName=polk&rs:Format=PDF